# Fread short values from a file with and store them into an int buffer

Tags: c, types

This might already have been discussed, but I couldn't find any related topic.

I want to read `short` values from a file and store them in a buffer of `int` values using `fread`. So basically I want to do this:

```
  int *data; //int buffer
  data = (int *) malloc(1000 * sizeof(int));
  fread(data, sizeof(short), 1000, infile); //infile is organized in 2-byte chunks
```

Data are stored in a file in 2-byte chunks (`short`). But when I read those data, I want to put them into an `int` buffer. How can I do that without copying from a `short` buffer to an `int` buffer? `fread` gets `void` pointer, so it doesn't care about the type of buffer.

Comment: Do not cast malloc: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fread` function doesn't know about types, that's correct. That's why it cant read raw bytes and convert them, it just puts them as-is into the provided buffer. And as you know, a `short` on most platforms is two bytes while `int` is four. So that will not work as `fread` has not idea about that.

You either read one short at a time, putting it into the `int` buffer, or read into a temporary `short` buffer then loop and copy value by value into the `int` buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Naja, you have to do that "copying from a short buffer to an int buffer", because if you just read your infile into data, it will just copy byte by byte from your file to the memory called data thus writing 2 shorts into one int.

Answer (score 1):

1) You can use `fscanf` with `%hu` and this works if the actual values are in text format, not binary.

```
unsigned short a
fp = fopen("myfile","r");
while(fscanf(fp,"%hu",&a))
{
    // put a in the array of unsigned short
}
```

2) You can use `fscanf` with `%c` and this works if the actual values are in binary format.

```
unsigned short a;
char b,c;
fp = fopen("myfile","r");
while(fscanf(fp,"%c",&b) && fscanf(fp,"%c",&c))
{
    a = (unsigned short) b;
    a = a << 8;
    a+= (unsigned short) c;
    // put a in the array of unsigned short
}
```

Comment: Only works if the actual values are in text format, not binary.